# Facebook share and like with callback doesn't run the callback and popup not opening every time

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-4.0

I was trying to implement a Facebook share and like function with a callback. But it does not run the callback. And it was also not triggering the popup 2nd time it clicked.

I want to run a callback after the like and share event. And also I need to open a popup every time I click the share/like button.

Facebook Doc also goes to 404.

```
 <a>
  <div class="social_net_button facebook_button">
    <script>
      (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/MY_PAGE" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="70" data-show-faces="false" data-action="like"></div>
  </div>
</a>







            $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
            FB.init({
                      appId: "{{env('FB_SECRET_KEY')}}",
                      version: 'v2.8',
                      display: 'popup',
                      status : true,
                      xfbml  : true,
                      autoLogAppEvents: true
                    });
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ URL("some-url") }}',
                    type: 'GET',
                })
                .done(function(response) {
                   toastr.info(response);
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    console.log("error");
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v15.0

It seems that `edge.create` is deprecated, so there is most likely no way to get any feedback anymore.

**Btw, be aware that you are not allowed to reward users in any way for liking or sharing.**

Comment: Ok Thanks, what is the equivalent for this event "edge.create" I can't find anything related to this event in the document you shared

Comment: there is no equivalent, it is just not possible anymore. you had "reward" in your code before, so i assume you would have used in a non-allowed way anyway, am i right? :)

Comment: btw, getting the info if something really got shared is not possible since many years anymore, even with the old edge.create event. i believe you could only get the info if the popup got opened.